# Core Data: How to update an NSArrayController immediately after adding an NSManagedObject?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsarraycontroller

I am adding an instance in core data. The entity is represented by an `NSArrayController`. I would like to access the newly added instance through the controller.

A "Skill" instance is added and then I try to access it through `selectAddedObject` as follows:

```
-(void)addSkill
{
    [self selectAddedObject:[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Skill"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
}

- (void)selectAddedObject:(NSManagedObject *)addedMO
{
    [self.sectionArrayController setSelectedObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:addedMO]];
    NSLog(@"Selected: %@", [self.sectionArrayController valueForKey:@"selectedObjects"]);
}
```

This only seems to work if I add

```
[self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
```

as the first line of `selectAddedObject:`. But once I do that, the document seems to forget that it still needs to save, and I could quit the app without my addition being auto-saved. Don't want to force that onto the users!

Any ideas on a way to immediately update the array controller in some other way? Or perhaps to add the object in another way? A few earlier answers (e.g. [Updating NSTableView when enitiy is added to core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124724/updating-nstableview-when-enitiy-is-added-to-core-data)) seem a bit outdated due to changes in OSX.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you got any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use the array controller to add the object. At some point during configuration, ensure the entity is set (`[self.sectionArrayController setEntityName:@"Skill"]`) and then do all of your work to create and select:

```
- (void)createAndSelectNewObject
{
    Skill *addedMO = [self.sectionArrayController newObject];

    if([self.sectionArrayController commitEditing]) {

        [self.sectionArrayController setSelectedObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:addedMO]];
        NSLog(@"Selected: %@", [self.sectionArrayController valueForKey:@"selectedObjects"]);
    }
}
```

You should commit any edits before changing the selection too (and only change the selection if the edits were committed or there weren't any).

Comment: Thanks, it looks very elegant this way. I do have a problem after trying this solution: `self.sectionArrayController` still has an unchanged number of objects after the commit! But the returned value is `YES`. Hmmm....

Comment: Just using `add:` on the array controller (in IB) also does not select the new object, not even with "Select inserted objects" checked in the interface builder.

Comment: What does work, is adding `[self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];`. I would really like to do without. Is there are reason why `-commitEditing` does not work, and `-processPendingChanges` does?

Comment: Although Wain's answer is a much more elegant way of accomplishing what I did in my code, I still have not found a way to avoid processPendingChanges. Does anyone have a further suggestion?